# REST call Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, curl

How do I make a call to a REST Api with Javascript (or ajax or jquery)?

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X PUT --user user:password http://url -d "{\"name\": \"Marcus0.2\",\"start\": 1361381326000,\"end\": 1361640526000}"
```

I need help converting this to a useable ajax call. Thanks

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'put',
    url: 'https://this.is.my/url',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { \"name\": \"Marcus0.3\" , \"start\": 500000 , \"end\": 1361640526000 }
    });
```

This code does not work [not sure why]. Also, 'https://this.is.my/url' is just short for the longer url, which I don't want to post online

Comment: Hmmm. Are you set against using jQuery? jQ sure makes it easy via `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Nope, I didn't know it was a possibility. Question updated

Comment: OK, just check out jQuery and the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: I did, but I struggling to get it to work. I'll update the question with my current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add escaping to your data element... you can send a whole object and jQuery will take care of it for you.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'put',
  url: 'https://this.is.my/url',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    name: 'Marcus0.3', 
    start: 500000,
    end: 1361640526000 
  }
});
```

Comment: Followup question: This call returns a dictionary. How can I save/access this dictionary? thanks

Comment: @IdeoREX, `$.ajax()` returns a promise, which you can use to add a callback to handle when the request is done.  This callback will get the data in an argument.  `$.ajax(/* ... */).done(function (data) { console.log(data); });`  See the example near the bottom of the documentation page:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/